# Sending Push Notification message to all users of my app (Windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I need to send a Push notification message to all users of my app. I understand that I need a URI which I receive from each user to send them back the message.

so, I have to register the ChannelUriUpdated event and send the URI to my server. 
In my server, I should store these data in a database, and use the list of URIs to send the message.

I'm not sure if that's the perfect method to do that. But if it is, How would I know if URI of a specific device gets updated from my server. I don't want to store multiple URIs in my database for each device.

Should I also send the GUID of the device with the unique URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a push URI is returned by MPNS it identifies a unique "app in device", i.e., every app installed in a device that requests for push notifications is given a different URI.

Now, I'm not responsible for the WP7 app, just the web servive part, but I think the app must revalidate the URI every time it launches.
In that case, You should update the URI you stored previously and that's why You should store the device id, so You can track and update the previous channel.

Also pay attention to response codes, as there are situations where You must stop sending new notifications as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941100(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When `Uri` of device is updated, you should replace old `Uri` on the server to the new one. So, one device - one Uri.

If you need to send notifications to all users without identification of each one and this requirement doesn't change in future - don't save GUID's. Just send notifications to stored `Uri`'s and that's all.

Comment: But in that case, I'll keep storing unused URI in my database. I tried to turn off the phone and switch on again. I got a different URI.

Comment: Oh, yes. Forgot about first part of a question. So, you answered your question - you need to send phone `GUID` to find old user `Uri` in database and update it accordingly

Comment: Thanks. so i see there is no other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I also send the GUID of the device with the unique URI?

That's were you're unclear: you got a one-to-many relationship between GUIDs which ***are*** unique per phone, and URIs which aren't.

You should store the GUIDs as primary key in your database, and URIs as column. Whenever you enter a new key, check if the GUID provided already exists in which case you `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.